# Why CHECK statement on MariaDB works on windows and not in linux?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

So, i was on database class yesterday on the college and the theacher tell us to make a simple excercise to show us how foreign keys work, so, i carry a laptop with antergos to the college, previuously i have installed MariaDB, but my fellows had MySQL on windows, we made the tables with a CHECK constraint to verify age >= 18, but it didn't work for everyone, i came across in MySQL manual that:

> CHECK is parsed but ignored.

BUT in my windows machine CHECK works with MariaDB and i don't know why.

[MariaDB prompt my Linux machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF53E.png)

[MariaDB prompt on my windows machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBQYu.png)

Version in windows: 10.3.7-MariaDB
Version in linux: 10.1.36-MariaDB

Comment: what is `SELECT VERSION()` on both?

Comment: In windows: 10.3.7-MariaDB
In linux: 10.1.36-MariaDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CHECK constraints was added to MariaDB version 10.2.1

See the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/constraint/#check-constraints) for more info

Comment: Oh, i see now, so... was CHECK ever implemented in MySQL? because my teacher was who told us to do that, and she was as confused about CHECK not working as us.

Thank you for the answer!

Comment: No, it is not implemented in MySQL. MySQL will accept the syntax but ignore it